# Newtonsoft.Json how to parse json property with smart quotes

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-4.8

I have JSON which contains property within quotes “” here is an example

```
{ 
  "data1" : "value",
  “data2” : {
     property : "property value"
  }
}
```

And my dto:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Data1 {get;set;}
    public object Data2 {get;set;}
}
```

and deserialization code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var jsonString = "   { \"data1\" : \"value\",“data2” : {property: \"property value\"}} ";
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonString);
}
```

On deserialization I'm getting an error:

```
'Invalid property identifier character: “. Path 'data1', line 1, position 23.'. Peace of stack trace  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseObject()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject ....
```

I there any workaround on how to fix it, maybe there is a possibility to additionally add another property identifier?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `jsonString=jsonString.Replace(new char[]{'“", '”'},'"')`?

Comment: What system would generate JSON like this? It's simply not valid, could it be because someone did a copy/paste into MS Word or similar? You should fix the JSON to make it valid.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON is just invalid (you can check that using a [validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#))

By replacing those fancy quotes it becomes valid so you should maybe consider applying a replace before parsing it?

```
jsonString = jsonString.Replace('“', '"');
```

But the best would be to fix the issue during the serialization because that JSON is invalid and will cause issue everywhere.

Comment: You should handle the closing quote as well `”`

Comment: yes, thanks for your answers. I did it as you advised like this 
`jsonString = jsonString.Replace("“", "\"").Replace("”", "\"");.`

Comment: Magnetron's comment in your question show a way to do it in one replace :-)